# Leaks in imageWithContentsOfFile ARC class in iOS 7

Tags: ios, memory-leaks

I have a leak in the line below, only in iOS 7. How do we fix this issue? I don't have other option like imageNamed and all, because I'm using the different bundle different target. Only option to read the image from bundle is imageWithContentsOfFile.

```
iconImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
@autoreleasepool
{
    iconImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it proper way in ARC class?

Comment: Main thread contain default autorelease pool. Then why do we need separate autorelease for UI update instance?